# How do I write the T-SQL syntax for this specific filtering process?

Tags: sql-server, filter, where-clause, sql-like

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a query which joins 3 tables for a specific output. An extract of one of the tables (called ResStayDate) is shown below:

```
ResID       StayDate      PlanCode
152        2015-08-02      COAI
152        2015-08-03      COAI
152        2015-08-04      COAI
296        2015-09-10      GBHB
296        2015-09-11      COHB
296        2015-09-12      GBHB
315        2015-09-23      FRBB
315        2015-09-24      FRBB
400        2015-10-02      CORB
400        2015-10-03      CORB
400        2015-10-04      CORB
```

The "real" table has more than 500,000 rows. I need to add a filter to my query so that it excludes ALL ResId whose full StayDates have PlanCode beginning with 'CO' but includes those ResID which have 'COR' as their PlanCode.

In other words, I want my query to output ResID 296 (as ALL of its StayDates do not begin with CO), 315 and 400.

Output:

```
ResID       StayDate      PlanCode
296        2015-09-10      GBHB
296        2015-09-11      COHB
296        2015-09-12      GBHB
315        2015-09-23      FRBB
315        2015-09-24      FRBB
400        2015-10-02      CORB
400        2015-10-03      CORB
400        2015-10-04      CORB
```

My query stands as follows and need to modified:

```
SELECT ResID, StayDate, PlanCode

FROM ResStayDate

WHERE PlanCode not like 'CO%'
```

However, the above line of codes will also exclude ResID 296 and 400.

Note: I am not showing the full query here (with its joins); I just need to understand the logic behind this specific filtering process and I will modify accordingly to fit my query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ResID, StayDate, PlanCode
FROM ResStayDate
WHERE (
    PlanCode not like 'CO%'
    OR PlanCode like 'COR%'
)
```

Comment: I don't get the same output. It excludes the line where ResID 296 has 'COHB' as PlanCode!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT ResID, StayDate, PlanCode
FROM ResStayDate
WHERE PlanCode not like 'CO%'
UNION ALL
SELECT ResID, StayDate, PlanCode
FROM ResStayDate
WHERE PlanCode like 'COR%'
```

This means that the first query will pull out all the records where the code does not start with CO and the second query will pull out the records where the code starts with COR.

Comment: This works, but if I saw someone use a UNION when they simply could have made an OR in the WHERE clause, I would be supremely unhappy with them.

Comment: UNION ALL has better performance, that's why I didn't propose an OR operator. Read this: http://sqltouch.blogspot.com.ar/2013/03/or-vs-union-all-have-you-thought-about.html

Comment: I am highly skeptical that a UNION ALL offers better performance. Equal performance perhaps... this is what I see when I compare the two against one of my large tables. And like all things with SQL, it's likely better or worse in slightly different scenarios and datasets.

Comment: the OR operator will perform a UNION under the hood, which tries to remove duplicates and in this case you know there are not gonna be duplicates in both queries. So, you are wasting time trying to do that while UNION ALL does't remove duplicates between the queries (the queries are already mutually exclusive). Run both queries and check the execution plan if you don't believe me.

Comment: IF there is an index on PlanCode the execution of either would be similar. If there is not an index on PlanCode the UNION ALL is going to be awful.

Comment: @Sean Lange what you said is right but we are dealing with a column that represents a code so there should be an index. There should "always" be an index on the columns you use for filtering the dataset.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein agreed there should be an index but I have seen plenty of systems that don't (or at least didn't until I added them). At the end of the day I don't see how either approach is going to make much difference assuming proper indexing is in place.

Comment: It's not a huge difference but OR removes duplicates and UNION ALL doesn't. That's why UNION ALL is faster but the difference might not even be noticeable, it really depends on the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I lose the row of ResID 296 where the PlanCode is 'COHB'. Basically, I want my output to include all the rows of a ResID which does not have all of its StayDates with a PlanCode starting with 'CO..'

Comment: But you said "...PlanCode beginning with 'CO' but includes those ResID which have 'COR' as their PlanCode...". If you also need COHB, simple add another UNION ALL SELECT ResID, StayDate, PlanCode
FROM ResStayDate
WHERE PlanCode like 'COH%'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe NOT LIKE 'CO[A-QS-Z]%' will work. Have not been able to test it though.